# Prove $A \subseteq (B \cap C) \iff (A \subseteq B)$ and $(A \subseteq C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some help with the following proof:

> $A \subseteq (B \cap C) \iff (A \subseteq B) \text{ and }(A \subseteq C)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$B\cap C\subset B\;\;\text{and also}\;\;B\cap C\subset C$$

Comment: Just from the defination.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of the radical change the original post suffered at the hand of its author.

Comment: Related for the $\Leftarrow$ proof: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218074/prove-if-a-subseteq-c-and-b-subseteq-d-then-a-cap-b-subseteq-c-cap-d?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

First: I suggest you convince yourself that $B\cap C \subseteq B$ and $B\cap C \subseteq C$, using only the definition of the **intersection of sets**, and of a **subset** of a set.

You can use element chasing to prove this, too.

$$[x \in B\cap C \iff (x \in B \text{ and } x \in C)] \iff (B\cap C \subseteq B \text{ and } B\cap C\subseteq C)$$

Now, you can use the above, and the method of element chasing, to prove $$A \subseteq (B \cap C) \iff (A \subseteq B) \text{ and }(A \subseteq C)\tag{$\dagger$}$$

recalling that $$X \subseteq Y \iff (x \in X \rightarrow x \in Y)$$

You can prove bidirectionality $(\iff)$ of the claim to be proven ($\dagger$) by sticking strictly to definitions.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment says, just use the definitions, and use the laws of logic...  You can calculate

\begin{align}
& A \subseteq B \cap C \\
= & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \implies x \in B \cap C \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \implies x \in B \land x \in C \rangle \\
= & \qquad \text{"logic: ..."} \\
\end{align}

Now do you see how to use two distribution rules from logic to get two separate parts, one about $\;B\;$ and one about $\;C\;$, so that you end up with the equivalent of $\;(A \subseteq B) \land (A \subseteq C)\;$?

You might want to rewrite $\;P \implies Q\;$ to $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$, if that makes it easier.